# Twilio Autopilot Dynamic Say Action with variables from memory

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I have a situation where I'm able to store additional details about a customer in memory . But Im unable to access them in the Task Definition .

E.g I'm storing the customer's last purchase amount and last purchase date to be presented if the customer wants to hear it as follows

```
{
"actions": [
    {
        "remember": {
            "last_Purchase": "17585",
            "last_Date":"25-Dec-2020"
        }
    },
    {
        "listen":True
    }
]
}
```

They get stored in the memory . However I'm unable to use this in a subsequent task (I'm not using it in the same task as Twilio doesnt supports it ) .

In a subsequent task I want to be able to create a dynamic Say in a task as follows

```
Dear Customer your last purchase is {memory.last_Purchase} on {memory.last_Date}.
```

But I guess the syntax is wrong or the way I'm accessing the memory variable is wrong .

Request guidance .

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In JavaScript, you'll need to put a money sign ("$") in front of the brackets surrounding your variable name, so your `Say` Action would look something like this in JavaScript, like in a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/manage):

```js
say = {
      "say": `Dear Customer your last purchase is ${memory.last_Purchase} on ${memory.last_Date}.`
    }
```

Additionally, objects saved with the `Remember` Action are placed at the top-level of the `Memory` object, so make sure you pull it out with `JSON.parse`:

```js
let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);
```

The total JS code (say, in a Twilio Function) would look something like

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let actions = [];
    let say = {};
    let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);

    say = {
      "say": `Dear Customer your last purchase is ${memory.last_Purchase} on ${memory.last_Date}.`
    }
    actions.push(say);
    let respObj = {
        "actions": actions
    };
    callback(null, respObj);    
};
```

Of course, alternatively, you could use

```js
say = {
      "say": "Dear Customer your last purchase is " + memory.last_Purchase + "on 
" + memory.last_Date
}
```

Comment: Hello so that means I'll have to supply the actions json by redirecting to a function or an external URL ? . Is it not possible to directly define it in the task definition (Program Task window ? )

Comment: Because your bot needs to use data from the current conversation context in the dialogue, this is a dynamic task/dynamically-generated Action. You need a Task to respond with dynamic Actions using the Redirect Action and Twilio Functions or your own endpoint. Using the Program Task window as you call it would be a static task does not use data from the context of the current conversation with the user in its dialogue.

Comment: that was useful .

Comment: If it was helpful and answered your question, would appreciate if you marked it as the answer!

Comment: So if I parse 'Inbound Context Parameters' into the Autopilot, how can I use them in Autopilot?